# Rotation of arbitrary plane around a given axis results in inconsistent results

Tags: python, rotation, plane, homogenous-transformation

I am trying to rotate and translate arbitrary planes around some arbitrary axis.
For testing purposes I have written a simple python program that rotates a random plane around the X axis in [image]  degrees.

Unfortunately when checking the angle between the planes I get inconsistent results. This is the code:

```
def angle_between_planes(plane1, plane2):
    plane1 = (plane1 / np.linalg.norm(plane1))[:3]
    plane2 = (plane2/ np.linalg.norm(plane2))[:3]
    cos_a = np.dot(plane1.T, plane2) / (np.linalg.norm(plane1) * np.linalg.norm(plane2))
    print(np.arccos(cos_a)[0, 0])


def test():
    axis = np.array([1, 0, 0])
    theta = np.pi / 2
    translation = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    T = get_transformation(translation, axis * theta)
    for i in range(1, 10):
        source = np.append(np.random.randint(1, 20, size=3), 0).reshape(4, 1)
        target = np.dot(T, source)
        angle_between_planes(source, target)
```

It prints:

```
1.21297144225
1.1614420953
1.48042948278
1.10098697889
0.992418096794
1.16954303911
1.04180591409
1.08015300394
1.51949177153
```

When debugging this code I see that the transformation matrix is correct, as it shows that it is
[image]

I'm not sure what's wrong and would love any assistance here.

*
The code that generates the transformation matrix is:

```
def get_transformation(translation_vec, rotation_vec):
    r_4 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]).reshape(1, 4)
    rotation_vec= rotation_vec.reshape(3, 1)
    theta = np.linalg.norm(rotation_vec)
    axis = rotation_vec/ theta
    R = get_rotation_mat_from_axis_and_angle(axis, theta)
    T = translation_vec.reshape(3, 1)
    R_T = np.append(R, T, axis = 1)
    return np.append(R_T, r_4, axis=0)



def get_rotation_mat_from_axis_and_angle(axis, theta):
    axis = axis / np.linalg.norm(axis)
    a, b, c = axis
    omct = 1 - np.cos(theta)
    ct = np.cos(theta)
    st = np.sin(theta)
    rotation_matrix =  np.array([a * a * omct + ct,  a * b * omct - c * st,  a * c * omct + b * st,
                                 a * b * omct + c * st, b * b * omct + ct,  b * c * omct - a * st,
                                 a * c * omct - b * st, b * c * omct + a * st, c * c * omct + ct]).reshape(3, 3)
    rotation_matrix[abs(rotation_matrix) < 1e-8] = 0
    return rotation_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

The `source` you generate is not a vector. In order to be one, it should have its fourth coordinate equal to zero.

You could generate valid ones with:

```
source = np.append(np.random.randint(1, 20, size=3), 0).reshape(4, 1)
```

---

Note that your code can't be tested as you pasted it in your question: for example, `vec = vec.reshape(3, 1)` in `get_transformation` uses `vec` that hasn't been defined anywhere before...

Comment: Thank you, I didnt notice the typo, fixed it now. Why the fourth coordinate should be 0?, I want to represent plane in homogeneous coordinates which are basically random (a, b, c, d)

Comment: The angle between planes is obtained by computing angles between the normal vectors to your planes. They should be normal vectors, with 3 coordinates (a, b, and c).  It's not very clear what `p1` and `p2` are supposed to be in your `angle_between_planes`. So, either you pass this function such vectors with 3 coordinates, or you pass it your 4 homogenous coordinates, but update the function to only use the first 3 ones. If you leave it unchanged, passing it (a1, b1, c1, 0) and (a2, b2, c2, 0), the coordinates of the normal vectors, does what you expect: calculate the angle between them.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. I changed the code in the question to match your correction but I still get inconsistent results..

Comment: @ShaulRobinov You won't get a pi/2 angle between your planes, unless they contain the direction of the rotation axis. Take for example a plane normal to the X axis: its image by the rotation will be itself, and the angle between the original and the rotated plane will be 0.